# PyCharm is failing to load the TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python

I am in the process of following through a tutorial to create a machine learning program using Python (PyCharm). I have installed the appropriate libraries and even though I have followed the tutorial to the letter I am left with the following error when I try to run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kanipoir/PycharmProjects/openaicart/cartGame.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\PycharmProjects\openaicart\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\kanipoir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

If anyone has any ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: It would probably be useful to include the link to the tutorial.

Comment: Hi, Pycharm is now setting up virtual enviroments when creating a proyect. How did you install the libraries?

Comment: @dmb I used pip install from the command prompt, if it still didn't accept it, there was a couple that I re-added just in case in pycharm's terminal. Do I need to add all specifically in the Pycharm terminal?

Comment: @DJK heres the link, I got stuck on this part: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-KvpNGudLw&list=WL&index=13&t=0s however it is a 6 part series I think. Everything worked up until now.